# How to update lables in a python frame class with (after) code

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm attempting a Python frame class with a lable that updates every time period.  I can't seem to get he configure thing to work for me.  Thanks

```
from tkinter import *                       # get base widget set
from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel
from datetime import datetime


class SensorUpdate(Frame) :
  def __init__(self) :
      Frame.__init__(self)
      self.pack()
      Label(self, text="Sensors").pack(anchor=NW)
      self.timeLabel = Label(self, 
      text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")).pack(anchor=NW)
      Button(self, text="Shut Down",command=(lambda :self.shutDown())).pack(side=RIGHT)
      self.after(500,self.updateImage)          #updates Frame Image
  
  def shutDown(self):
        print("in shutDown")
        ans = askokcancel('Verify', "Really quit?")
        if ans: 
            print("made it here")
            SensorUpdate.quit(self)
    
  def updateImage(self):
      print(" Updating Image")
      now = datetime.now()
      current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
      print(current_time)
      #self().timeLabel.configure(text='Test')  # object not callable
      #self.timeLabel.configure(text='Test')    # object has no attribute timeLabel
      #timeLabel.configure(text='Test')               # timeLabel not found
      self.after(10,self.updateImage)
  
root = Tk()
app = SensorUpdate()
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: You have to call `configure` on the label. It won't just automatically pick up the value of a local variable.

Comment: I'm not sure where you mean.  I tried each of the configures shown above with errors shown on the right when i did.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some quality time with 3000 pages of Lutz texts, I've found a solution using two classes one for the basics of display and one for the update using the (after) command. Any help on my first method is apprecieated.  I can make this work at least even if I'm not sure why the first one doesn't

```
from tkinter import *                       # get base widget set
from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel
from datetime import datetime

class SensorConfig:
     size = 200                                        
     bg, fg = 'beige', 'brown'                        

class IndicatorDisplay(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, cfg):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timeLabel = Label(self)
        self.timeLabel.config(bd=20,relief=SUNKEN,bg=cfg.bg,fg=cfg.fg)
        self.timeLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, text="Shut Down",command=(lambda :self.shutDown())).pack(side=RIGHT)
  
    def shutDown(self):
        print("in shutDown")
        ans = askokcancel('Verify', "Really quit?")
        if ans: 
            print("made it here")
            self.quit()

    def onUpdate(self, curTime):
        self.timeLabel.config(text=curTime)

class Sensor(Frame):
    def __init__(self, config=SensorConfig, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill = BOTH)
        self.cfg = config
        self.display = IndicatorDisplay(self, self.cfg)                     
        self.display.pack(side=TOP)
        self.updateLabels()

    def updateLabels(self):
        print("make time change")
        self.display.onUpdate(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))  
        self.after(500, self.updateLabels)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = SensorConfig()
    mySensor = Sensor(config)
    mySensor.mainloop()
```